# Getting 404 not found code after submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms, http-status-code-404

I have a assignment due to tomorrow and cant find the solution.
After submitting getting a 404 not found code back.
Html and php code are in the same file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if (isset($_POST['subject']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['subject'] as $subject)
            echo '<img src="img/' . $subject . '.jpg">';
    }
    else
        echo "Select a car of your choosing!";
}
?>

<html lang="en">
<body>
<form method='post'>
    <select name="subject" multiple size=4>
        <option value='Ferrari'>Ferrari</option>
        <option value='Lambo'>Lambo</option>
        <option value='Audi'>Audi</option>
        <option value='VW'>VW</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=Submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you submit the form, is the url in your browser changing?  Is the 404 on the page load or on the attempted load of the images?  Is there any javascript related to this?

Comment: when i submit the form the url is not changing,and no there is no javascript related to this its all php and html.

Comment: Okay, so what about the second question then?  If the url is not changing, then it is quite hard to believe that the page would be found the first time you load it, but not the second.  Perhaps it is actually the _images_ that are not found?

Comment: the 404 page is load and im not sure how to fix that the images are not found? img map is in the same map as the php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't enclosed the value of your submit button.
Also change the form code to what I posted below, this should fix your issue.

FROM:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=Submit>
```

TO:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```